# Is "chándal" a commonly used term in Mexico and the rest of Latin America?

Tags: vocabulario, méxico, hispanoamérica

I was looking for ways to translate "tracksuit" or "windbreaker" and came across **cortaviento** and **chándal**. Which one of the two is preferred in Mexican or Latin American spanish?

Comment: In Chile is unknown. A while advertising a brand of clothing used the French word "chandail" to refer to what we know as "buzo" (sporty two-piece suit) but did not work.

Comment: My understanding (from the usage in castilian Spanish) is that "chándal" is a two piece sportwear (pants and upper part) while "cortavientos" is just a single piece of clothing (that you could actually wear on top of your "chándal" when jogging/running if its cold, rainy or windy).

Comment: The common word in Colombia (or at least in Bogotá) is _«cortavientos»_ (as many other verb-noun composed words, it usually ends in _«-s»_, even with a singular article). The word _«chándal»_ is alien to me.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón Is contravientos also used for tracksuits in Colombia?

Comment: [This reference](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ch%C3%A1ndal) implies that is not known im Mexico, and _pans_ (or _pants_) is used instead (but maybe Rodrigo will want to help validating that content. Is really _salida de cancha_ used?).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know Wiktionary had different amount of information for the same entries in different language editions. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

So, we knew that [the Wiktionary](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ch%C3%A1ndal) explained what a *chándal* is in castilian Spanish, and gave a couple of synonyms for other countries that have been validated by some users in the comments (such as *buzo* in Chile).

I found a Mexican online clothing store and tried, [successfully](http://www.linio.com.mx/catalog/?q=chandal&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linio.com.mx), to find a *chándal*. Interestingly, they use *chamarra* to designate the upper part of the *chándal* and not *chaqueta* or *chaquetilla*.

So, it seems that in Mexico they use, or at least would understand *chándal*. I tried to find the *pan/pants* that the Wiktionary say is the Mexican word for *chándal* and [it seems to be](http://www.linio.com.mx/catalog/?q=pants&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linio.com.mx) another piece of sportwear, but just the lower part (*pantalones*).

Just to be sure, I checked [more than one Mexican online store](http://listado.mercadolibre.com.mx/chandal-adidas), and there I could find a *chándal*, *pants de chándal* (no "pantalones de chándal" that would be said in Spain, for example) and *chamarras*.

So I would say that *chándal* is commonly used in Mexico (and Spain) but not in all the other countries (we know is *buzo* in Chile thanks to Rodrigo and *cortavientos* in Colombia thanks to Carlos Eugenio).